# Warning Shlokas to liar

Tags: scripture, vedas

Are there any valuable shlokas in the Vedas, especially in Dharma sastras, which warn liars or ones who deceive people?  And I'd like to know what will happen to a liar and deceitful person after death. Also what will happen to one who lie to a brahmana or a saintly person like a guru.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hinduism, sins are divided into three categories -- 1. mental sins (sins committed by thoughts) 2. verbal sins (committed by speech) and 3. bodily sins (those committed by actions).

In this classification, lying comes under type 2 i.e. sins committed by verbal actions.

Manu Smiti has the relevant verses:

> 12.5. Coveting the property of others, thinking in one’s heart of what is undesirable, and adherence to false (doctrines), are the three
> kinds of (sinful) mental action.
>
> **12.6. Abusing (others, speaking) untruth, detracting from the merits of all men, and talking idly, shall be the four kinds of (evil) verbal
> action.**

And, similarly there are sins that fall under type3. Now, all these sins have certain consequences.

For example, verbal sins result in that Jiva getting born as a beast or a bird.

> 12.9. In consequence of (many) sinful acts committed with his body, a man becomes (in the next birth) something inanimate, **in consequence
> (of sins) committed by speech, a bird, or a beast**, and in
> consequence of mental (sins he is re-born in) a low caste.

> Also what will be happened to one who lie to brahmana or saintly
> person like guru.

Lying to Guru (or lying in front of Guru) is a much bigger sin than what lying in any other situation is.

Lord Shiva says the following:

> sAmAnyato nishidhancha tad-guro yadi sannidhau |
>  Acharettasya
> sarvashya doshah koti-guno bhavet ||
>
> (An action) What is generally prohibited, if done in the vicinity of
> the Guru, assumes the form of a sin of a much bigger proportion.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 12.97**

Therefore. if lying is a sin, lying in front of Guru is a much bigger sin. The verse uses "koti-guno bhavet" i.e. "multiplied by a crore" which means the sin gets magnified manifold times.

Comment: @Radhikadasi If you're satisfied with this answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons. if you like it you may press the up arrow for voting.

Comment: Dear Archit, Thank you for your edited and advice (^o^)

Comment: Dear Rickross, you always help me. Thank you so much. I'd like to know more. Do you know what kind of hell are waiting for liars who mislead people to wrong path?

Comment: Thanks @Radhikadasi regarding the hell part I have to check.

Comment: Dear Rickross, I got better idea for you and all other people. I'll make "Questions" topic regarding to "what kind of hell are waiting for liars who mislead people to wrong path". Then it will help you liability relief and give spiritual benefit  to other people. Thank you (^o^)

Comment: Yes good idea @Radhikadasi